# Squeaky Fan, Unknown Model/Make

Tags: electrical, repair, ceiling-fan

We bought our house 4 years ago with this fan in our bedroom.

Over the past year, it has developed a whirring noise, it doesn't sound like loose a loose screw or other fastener, but rather electrical in nature. I've cleaned the blades to no effect. The only visible screws to disassemble are located at the top of the unit near to where it meets the ceiling.

I've been unable to locate any identifying information on the fan itself.

Does anyone have any idea what make/model this is (*pictures attached*)?

Also, any suggestions for addressing the whirring?

[image][image]

Comment: Whirring, squeaking or electronic hum ?

Comment: Is it on a speed controller?

Comment: It somewhere between a whirring and a electric hum. It is also intermittent. It is on a speed controller, it only makes the noise when on the highest setting.

Comment: What make and model is the speed controller?